# Linear Algebra: 2x2 matrix with lambda

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given the question

> Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}\lambda &-2  \\ -3 & \lambda-1 \end{pmatrix}$
>
> > a) for what value/s of $\lambda$ is $A$ invertible?

> > b) for these value/s of $\lambda$, find $A^{-1}$

I know what to do once I've found the values of $\lambda$, but I'm not sure about how to find the values. So far I've basically been trying numbers by hand to see what works and what doesn't. Should I be doing this another way?

I've tried $-10$ to $10$ individually and the only ones that don't work so far are $-2$ and $+3$.

Comment: Two approaches you may take is calculating the determinant and row-reducing the matrix.

Comment: calculate the determinant. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find Det (A) first.A is inverteble if and only if
Det (A) is not equal to 0.Then you can use  gauss elimination and elementary row operations or cramers rule
Det(A)=(x-3)(x+2) so it is inverteble for all x which  is not equal to 3 or -2

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $\det A$, we have $$A^{-1}=\dfrac1{\det A}\,\operatorname{com}(A),$$
where $\,\operatorname{com}(A)$, the comatrix of $A$, is the matrix of cofactors of $\:{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-5mu}A$, which is easy to compute for a $2{\times}2$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at what values of $\lambda$ do not work first. For a $2\times 2$ matrix, $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}$ the determinant is $ad-bc$. So when you plug in your values you should arrive at the following: $\lambda^{2}-\lambda-6\neq 0$. Solve the quadratic and you have the values for $\lambda$ that will not work.